Running a specific task only from a DAG in Apache Airflow
Is there a way in Apache Airflow to run a single task from a DAG on an adhoc basis, controlling whether it runs with only its upstream or downstream tasks without running the whole DAG?,
similar to how the dbt CLI allows selecting specific models to run
dbt run --select +model_name+


You can use the branch python operator with a parameter passed to the DAG to decide which task to run.       https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/python/index.html#airflow.operators.python.BranchPythonOperator

If you wish to run a task and all downstream tasks instead of whole DAG, you could manually clear the task.
For example,  task1 >> task2 >> task3,  in airflow UI, just click "task2" and then click "Clear" in the pop menu,  it will run task2 and task3.
If you wish to run a task and all up tasks instead of whole DAG, I don't think airflow support this kind of behaviors, because you could imagine that airflow run tasks as a graph, it's possible to start from a "root", but impossible to end as a "leaf".
In this scenario, you may comment useless tasks in code level.
